# Lagrange multipliers question and my attempt

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Question is to minimise the $f(x,y)$ = $3x^{2} + y^{2} - x $$$$$    and constraint is given by $2x^{2} + y^{2} =1 $

Question is simple and ii have got most of points but i seem to miss few points which indeed  is lack of my equation solving which i need to clear here ..Here see my attempt and then correct me .<<<<

Is there a well defined way for obtaining critical points in lagrange multiplier questions...>>>Thanks

[image: Attempt]

[image: ATTEMPT]

Comment: Please read the help pages how to write a question.

Comment: @Karl .my apologies .i will learn that soon but first my exams are near . so to save time i do this